# How to get distinct count of keys along with other aggregations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

My data frame (DF) looks like this

```
Customer_number Store_number   year   month   last_buying_date1  amount     
     1             20          2014    10      2015-10-07        100
     1             20          2014    10      2015-10-09        200
     2             20          2014    10      2015-10-20        100
     2             10          2014    10      2015-10-13        500
```

and I want to get an output like this

```
 year   month  sum_purchase count_purchases distinct customers 
 2014    10       900          4                  3
```

How do I get an output like this using Agg and group by . I am using a 2 step group by currently  but struggling to get the distinct customers . Here's my approach

```
#### Step 1 - Aggregating everything at customer_number, store_number level
aggregations = {
    'amount': 'sum',       
    'last_buying_date1': 'count',
    }
grouped_at_Cust = DF.groupby(['customer_number','store_number','month','year']).agg(aggregations).reset_index()
grouped_at_Cust.columns =   ['customer_number','store_number','month','year','total_purchase','num_purchase']


#### Step2 - Aggregating at year month level 


aggregations = {
    'total_purchase': 'sum',       
    'num_purchase': 'sum',
     size
    }

Monthly_customers =       grouped_at_Cust.groupby(['year','month']).agg(aggregations).reset_index()
Monthly_customers.colums = ['year','month','sum_purchase','count_purchase','distinct_customers']
```

My struggle is in the 2nd step. How do i include size in the 2nd aggregation step ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`groupby.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and supplying the function [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) to return number of unique Customer Ids in the group.

```
df_grp = df.groupby(['year', 'month'], as_index=False)                                 \
           .agg({'purchase_amt':['sum','count'], 'Customer_number':['nunique']})

df_grp.columns = map('_'.join, df_grp.columns.values)

df_grp
```

[image]

---

Incase, you are trying to group them differently (omitting certain column) when performing `groupby` operation:

```
df_grp_1 = df.groupby(['year', 'month']).agg({'purchase_amt':['sum','count']})       

df_grp_2 = df.groupby(['Store_number', 'month', 'year'])['Customer_number'].agg('nunique')
```

Take the first level of the multiindex columns which contains the `agg` operation performed:

```
df_grp_1.columns = df_grp_1.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Merge them back on the intersection of the columns used to group them:

```
df_grp = df_grp_1.reset_index().merge(df_grp_2.reset_index().drop(['Store_number'], 
                                      axis=1), on=['year', 'month'], how='outer')
```

Rename the columns to new ones:

```
d = {'sum': 'sum_purchase', 'count': 'count_purchase', 'nunique': 'distinct_customers'}  

df_grp.columns = [d.get(x, x) for x in df_grp.columns]
df_grp
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Nickil. But my customer is defined as a combination of customer_number and store_number. How to I combine them to do nunique ?

Comment: Are the `purchase_amt` sum/count calculated without using `store_number` to be one of the grouped objects? If that's the case you would need to do `groupby` twice for different selections. *See edit*

Comment: Please see the updated example (edited  the question). A customer is not just customer_number rather a combination of customer_number and store_number. So ,if I could concatenate customer_number and store number, and implement you solution using  `nunique` , that will work. But concat will lead to other problems.

Comment: Do you mean to take the summation of all unique entries looking into both `Customer_number` and `Store_number` columns: `df.groupby(['Store_number'])['Customer_number'].agg(['nunique']).sum().to_frame().T`?

Comment: The SQL equivalent of what I want to achieve will be .. `Select month, year , sum(total_amount) as sum_purchase, sum(num_purchases) as count_purchase, count (*) as distinct_customers  from (select customer_number , store_number, month, year, sum(amount) as total_amount , count(*) as num_purchase from original_table group by customer_number,store_number,month,year ) a  group by month,year`

Comment: I'm not well versed with the SQL syntax. From what is shown, you are simply counting the combination of number of unique entries in both `Customer_number` and `Store_number` columns and aggregating it which is the same as finding `nunique` and taking their sum across groups. Sorry for not being able to solve your problem.

Comment: Appreciate the help in any case @Nickil -